# Raspberry Pi will not detect mpu6050

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpu6050

I have an mpu6050 and I am trying to get it to work with my raspberry pi. I the following pins connected to the raspberry pi like this:

> vcc --------- 5V (pin 4)
>
> gnd --------- Ground (pin 6)
>
> scl --------- scl (pin 5)
>
> sda --------- sda (pin 3)
>
> xda --------- not connected
>
> xcl --------- not connected
>
> add --------- not connected
>
> int --------- not connected

When I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`, I get:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

The green light on the mpu6050 is on. Also, the day before the mpu6050 was working fine.

Comment: Is it possible it's on a different bus? I remember having a problem some years ago finding my device and it ended up being on a different bus
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97973/raspberry-pi-multiple-i2c-busses

Comment: i checked and it only has 1 bus

Comment: Are you able to detect any other devices on i2c?

Comment: http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/575

Comment: i don't have any other devices to test

Comment: I would suggest getting another cheap, simple device (temp or humidity sensor?) and seeing if you have the same issue with that as well. At this point it's impossible to tell if it's with your wiring, the device, the PI, or some configuration

Comment: i tryed doing everything in the link you sent me but i still cant detect anything

Comment: You also mentioned it was working fine the day before... In that case it's possible it's bricked. If you plug in another device and it works then your mpu6050 is dead. This can be caused by improper wiring, a short or static electricity.

Comment: yeah its probebly bricked, i tryed connecting it to an arduino and running a script i found online for it and the same thing happened. the green light turned on but the arduino (or the program) couldent find the mpu. well, thank you for your time.